# Namespace with extend from wordpress class not working

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm having trouble with namespaces. When I put a namespace, my application will look for the class I extend in the namespace, while I want my namespace to be for my Quote_Recieved class.

```php
namespace emails;

class Quote_Received extends WC_Email { 
...
```

But I have this error :

`Uncaught Error: Class 'emails\WC_Email' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\.....`

How I can put my namespace for Quote_Received and not WC_Email ?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `\WC_Email`, so that it looks for the class in the global namespace.

Comment: Thank @CBroe it's work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is solved by @CBroe and his comment :

> Use \WC_Email, so that it looks for the class in the global namespace